# The temporary folder is cleaned automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, temp

I write temporary files to a temporary folder like this:

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(originalFilePath);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

I write large files of images. So, I have a question - a temporary folder is cleaned itself over time? Or do I need to when the application exit delete all temporary files?

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: You should clean up your mess, Windows won't do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to clean your temporary file at application exit.
Create a class that manage temporary resources and use destructor to delete the temporary file(s).

```
public class TemporaryFile
{
    private string _fileName = String.Empty;

    <other stuffs...>

    ~TemporaryFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(_fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Perhaps throw `IDisposable` in there for good measure.

Comment: No reason to use destructor/finalizer here. Use finalizer only when directly dealing with unmanaged resources.

Comment: Ok, you can modify the class to use IDisposable, just keep the basic idea.